# custom dots slick.js slickGoTo not working

Tags: javascript, jquery, slick.js

I tried making a carousel with slick js and make custom dots. (I make this custom dots since I need the dots to be outside of carousel div, so it's no use telling me to use "dots: true" parameter). here is the fiddle

http://jsfiddle.net/sjkdpcjo/49/

```
<div class="paging-group">
  <ul>
    <li data-page="1">
      <button>1</button>
    </li>
    <li data-page="2">
      <button>2</button>
    </li>
    <li data-page="3">
      <button>3</button>
    </li>
  </ul>
</div>

<section class="main-carousel">
  <div class="carousel">
    <div class="carousel-item">1</div>
    <div class="carousel-item">2</div>
    <div class="carousel-item">3</div>
    <div class="carousel-item">4</div>
    <div class="carousel-item">5</div>
    <div class="carousel-item">6</div>
    <div class="carousel-item">7</div>
    <div class="carousel-item">8</div>
    <div class="carousel-item">9</div>
    <div class="carousel-item">10</div>
    <div class="carousel-item">11</div>
    <div class="carousel-item">12</div>
    <div class="carousel-item">13</div>
    <div class="carousel-item">14</div>
    <div class="carousel-item">15</div>
    <div class="carousel-item">16</div>
  </div>
</section>
```

the javascript code

```
carousel.slick({
  dots: true,
  slidesToShow: 4,
  slidesToScroll: 4,
  arrows: false,
  infinite: false,
  dots: false,
});

$( '.paging-group ul li' ).click( function() {
    var page = $( this ).data( 'page' );
    console.log( page );
    carousel.slick('slickGoTo', page);
});
```

it's weird, since it won't go to other page except first page (try to slide / swipe to any page except the first one, and click the dots).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The slickToGo function asks for the **item number** as parameter, **not the page number**. The reason why it always goes to the first page is because all items (1, 2, and 3) are all on the first page. You can change the code as follows, assuming there is always exactly 4 items per page:

```
carousel.slick('slickGoTo', (page - 1) * 4 + 1);
```

In this case, if the user clicks 2 (for page 2), it will call slickGoTo on item number 5, which is the beginning of page 2.